# how can i upload multiple files to s3 using nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

please I'm lost how can I upload multiple files

This is how I upload single files:

```html
 <div class="a-row a-spacing-top-medium">
   <label class="choosefile-button">
      <i class="fal fa-plus"></i>
      <input
          type="file"
          @change="onFileSelected"
          ref="files"
      />
      <p style="margin-top: -70px">{{ fileName }}</p>
   </label>
</div>
```

this is my script tag for image upload:

```html
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedFile: null,
      fileName: '',
      photos: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onFileSelected(event) {
      this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0]
      console.log(this.selectedFile)
      this.fileName = event.target.files[0].name
    },
    async onAddProduct() {
      let data = new FormData()
      data.append('photos', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name)
      const response = await axios
        .post('http://localhost:5000/api/products', data)
        .then(() => {
          console.log(response)
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

each time I add multiple to my input tag it just uploads an image in my browser.

Please how can I go about multiple uploads?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic [blog post](https://www.concentrationcode.com/uploading-vue/) on how to upload a files to S3 in Vue through a node backend. This may help you out.

Basically what you need to do is create a backend that handles the files and uploads them. This can be done using `multer`, `multer-s3` and node.

One thing that you should also change is just having

```
data.append('photos', this.selectedFile)
data.append('fileName', this.selectedFile.name)
```